# How to compare two strings and find the percentage of similarity

Tags: c#, string, comparison

The below code does the job, but takes lot of time. Am comparing the contents of two HTML files which I have saved as a string in MongoDB already. And the length of the string is around 30K+ and have around 250K+ records to compare. Thus the job is taking quite lot of time.

Is there any easier way or plugin to use and is quite fast too?

```
private int ComputeCost(string input1, string input2)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input1))
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input2) ? 0 : input2.Length;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input2))
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input1) ? 0 : input1.Length;

    int input1Length = input1.Length;
    int input2Length = input2.Length;

    int[,] distance = new int[input1Length + 1, input2Length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= input1Length; distance[i, 0] = i++) ;
    for (int j = 0; j <= input2Length; distance[0, j] = j++) ;

    for (int i = 1; i <= input1Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= input2Length; j++)
        {
            int cost = (input2[j - 1] == input1[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

            distance[i, j] = Math.Min(
                                Math.Min(distance[i - 1, j] + 1, distance[i, j - 1] + 1),
                                distance[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }

    return distance[input1Length, input2Length];
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what "[Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)" is for?

Comment: You're computing *Edit Distance*, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance right?

Comment: Why aren't you comparing the strings in the database itself? I'd give it a try, as it usually is faster.

Comment: Yes Dmitry, return (1.0 - (ComputeCost(string1, string2)/ (double)Math.Max(input1.Length, input2.Length))) * 100; This gives the similarity percentage.

Comment: If possible, make the method static and it's much faster. The method have to do his job 30 K+ * 250 K+ times. Let the method stay long in the heap memory to response immediately. Maybe, it seems you evaluated Levhenstein distance as well and I'm not sure which one is more speedy.

Comment: As of my case, most critical point was reducing the amount of data by excluding uncessary data and dividing and processing with multi-threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Kay Lee, made the function static and used HTML agility pack to remove unnecessary data. And saw a good performance improvement.